# DropDownListFor overload htmlAttributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How do I add `htmlAttributes` using this overload:

I'm using the below overload:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.Type.Value, new SelectList(ViewBag.DropDownLoadRecoveryType,  "Value", "Text", item.Type))
```

I like to add `htmlattributes` to the above overload and i do not see any overloads that support unless I'm missing something.

```
new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, Object)`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.Type.Value, 
    new SelectList(ViewBag.DropDownLoadRecoveryType,  "Value", "Text", item.Type),
    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: @AbuHamzah No worries :)